# Output of streamline in Matlab is empty

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to use streamline to show a vector field. The vector field is singular in a point. I want to remove regions near the singularity (fo example regions which their distance to singularity is less than 1). I wrote below code but it doesn't show anything. Could anyone help me?

```
clear all;
close all;
r1 = 1; r2 = 5;  % Radii of your circles
x_0 = 0; y_0 = 0; % Centre of circles
[x,y] = meshgrid(x_0-r2:0.2:x_0+r2,y_0-r2:0.2:y_0+r2); % meshgrid of points

idx = ((x-x_0).^2 + (y-y_0).^2 > r1^2 & (x-x_0).^2 + (y-y_0).^2 < r2^2);
x = sort(x(idx));
[x, index] = unique(x);
y = sort(y(idx));
[y, index] = unique(y);
U=cos(x)/sqrt(x.^2+y.^2);
V=sin(x)/sqrt(x.^2+y.^2);
streamslice(x,y,U,V);
```

Comment: @Wolfie could you please help? I'm sure you are the one who could answer these questions

Comment: This *still* isn't about MATLAB GUI development. The [tag:matlab-guide] tag should not be here.

Comment: I edited the question. Do you know what is the problem? @beaker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `U` and `V` are all zeros, so you get white space. The reason for that is that you don't use elementwise division with `./`. So as a first step you should write:

```
U = cos(x)./sqrt(x.^2+y.^2);
V = sin(x)./sqrt(x.^2+y.^2);
```

Now `U` and `V` are not zeros but are also not matrices anymore, so they are not a valid input for `streamslice`. The reason for that is that `x` and `y` are converted to vectors when calling:

```
x = sort(x(idx));
y = sort(y(idx));
```

My guess is that you can remove all this indexing, and simply write:

```
r1 = 1; r2 = 5;  % Radii of your circles
x_0 = 0; y_0 = 0; % Centre of circles
[x,y] = meshgrid(x_0-r2:0.2:x_0+r2,y_0-r2:0.2:y_0+r2); % meshgrid of points
U = cos(x)./sqrt(x.^2+y.^2);
V = sin(x)./sqrt(x.^2+y.^2);
streamslice(x,y,U,V);
```

so you get:

[image: streamslice]

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the concept of *streamslice*. Is this you expecting?

```
close all;
r1 = 1; r2 = 5;  % Radii of your circles
x_0 = 0; y_0 = 0; % Centre of circles
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(x_0-r2:0.2:x_0+r2,y_0-r2:0.2:y_0+r2); % meshgrid of points

% idx = ((xx-x_0).^2 + (yy-y_0).^2 > r1^2 & (xx-x_0).^2 + (yy-y_0).^2 < r2^2);
% x = sort(xx(idx));
% [x, index] = unique(x);
% y = sort(yy(idx));
% [y, index] = unique(y);
U=cos(xx)./sqrt(xx.^2+yy.^2);
V=sin(xx)./sqrt(xx.^2+yy.^2);
streamslice(xx,yy,U,V);
```